# Testcase failing in Jenkins however running in msbuild command line

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, coded-ui-tests, vstest

The Coded UI tests are running successfully in the MSTest or vstest.console.exe.

However when running the same command in Jenkins the tests are failing giving the below error(using vstest.console.exe).

Error calling Initialization method for test class MyServiceTestSuite: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: To run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test agent to run as an interactive process. For more information, see "How to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests That Interact with the Desktop" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255012)
If you are running the tests as part of your team build, you must also set up the build agent to run as an interactive process. For more information, see "How to: Configure and Run Scheduled Tests After Building Your Application" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254735)

Is there any way to run the tests successfully in Jenkins without installing Test Agent.